# Can't Print the RDLC report when I deploy onto another computer?

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

When i run this on VS it works fine but when i run it on another computer it cant find the RDLC path.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LocalReport localReport = new LocalReport();
        ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
        reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Pallet_label", lb_pallet_name.Text));
        reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("Par_PalNum", LB_Number.Text));

        localReport.ReportPath = Application.StartupPath + "\\pallet_label.rdlc";


        localReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
     
       
        localReport.PrintToPrinter();

       }
```

Comment: At a risk of asking the obvious: Does pallet_label.rdlc exist in the application startup path on that "other computer"?

Comment: The file path is \OneDrive\library_app\Library Sys App\pallet_label.rdlc

Comment: Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: An error occurred during local report processing. ---> System.ApplicationException: The report definition for report 'pallet_label' has not been specified ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\GORDO\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\YMRY4CDT.J9D\7NEM6X2V.H82\libr..tion_dd410a5f2cfa6aca_0001.0000_5e21d986a62a9ef5\pallet_label.rdlc'.

Comment: If the file path is \OneDrive\... etc., then why do you write "Application.StartupPath" in your code instead of "\OneDrive\..."?

Comment: Its still the same error if i use: localReport.ReportPath =  @"C:\Users\GORDO\OneDrive\library_app\Library Sys App\pallet_label.rdlc";

Comment: And does that file exist in that location on that other computer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242689/discussion-between-gordon-and-heinzi).